# Is there any way to put recyclerview and linearlayout in swiperefreshlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

If I put only `RecyclerView` into `SwipeRefreshLayout` I have buttons above `RecyclerView`. And if I put all into `SwipeRefresh` I have buttons disappear

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/students_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonsLayout">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/selectAllButton"
            android:text="Выбрать всех"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwipeRefreshLayout accepts only one child, so maybe you can have a ConstraintLayout inside the SwipeRefreshLayout, and the RecyclerView with the Buttons inside the ConstraintLayout.

PS: I suggest a ConstraintLayout to avoid nested layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/students_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/selectAllButton"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/selectAllButton"
            android:text="Выбрать всех"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this with linearlayout with buttons and it works.